# Try / except syntax in Python with two of the same exceptions

Tags: python, django

I am checking emails against two lists -- a list of domains and a list of individual emails.
How would I construct the following try statement --

```
Try: 'email in email_list'

Except DoesNotExist: 'domain in domain list' # if email not found

Except DoesNotExist: 'print error message'   # if both email and domain not found
```

What syntax do I need to use to construct this statement?

Comment: Clarifications, please: 1) Is it possible for one email to fail BOTH tests and you want to catch BOTH?  2) Do you have control of the code that is raising the exception?

Comment: If this is Django, you're doing your imports wrong.  Please post more code, showing you're `import` statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like:

```
if email in email_list:
    # do something with email
elif domain in domain_list:
    # do something with domain
else:
    print "neither email nor domain found"
```

There is probably no need for exceptions in this case.

Comment: So there is no way how to do this A) following the "ask forgiveness" principle and B) avoiding both repetition like: `if 'foo' in somedata: y = somedata['foo']; elif 'bar' in somedata: y = somedata['bar']; ...` and deep nesting? (Notice repetition of both key and dict name in all cases)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't define two exceptions: `DomainDoesNotExists`, `EmailDomainDoesNotExists` ?

```
try: 
    'email in email_list'
except DomainDoesNotExists:
    ...
except EmailDomainDoesNotExists:
    ...
```

There is no way to do what you want with only one Exception type (e.g. DoesNotExists).

But you better listen to @Greg Hewgill, in this case you don't need exceptions

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what you are trying to do.  Your capitalizations are a problem.  When you catch exceptions, proceed from the most specific to the general.  The first handler block handles the exception and puts you out of the try-except progression.

```
try:
    yourEmailRoutine
except DomainDoesNotExist:
    ##code to be carried out if domain does not exist...
    print "The domain %s does not exist." % yourDomainName
```

Since emails are often malformed, you might want to use Greg's suggestion to deal with this in an if-elif-else progression.